# Remove key data in dingo - fractal

Tags: transformer-model, dingo-api

I already looked into several example on how to remove the key "data" in response, but i cannot fix it.

I tried to use the callback provided by dingo

```
return $this->collection($users, new UserTransformer, function ($resource, $fractal) {
    $fractal->setSerializer(new ArraySerializer);
});
```

In change the "$fractal->setSerializer(new CustomSerializer);" to "$fractal->setSerializer(new ArraySerializer);" since I dont have CustomSerializer(And how to make this custom serializer?) based on the fractal documentation [array serializer](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/serializers/) but the out put has the key "data".

I also tested the fractal library in different project and implementing the ArraySerializer as the Serializer, and it works.

What am I missing in the setup of dingo-fractal?

**UPDATE***
I included the setup in the [config](https://joshhornby.co.uk/blog/laravel-dingo-json-api-spec)

```
$this->app->bind('Dingo\Api\Transformer\Adapter\Fractal', function($app) {
        $fractal = $app->make('\League\Fractal\Manager');
        $serializer = new \League\Fractal\Serializer\ArraySerializer();

        $fractal->setSerializer($serializer);
        return new \Dingo\Api\Transformer\Adapter\Fractal($fractal);
    });
```

And in my controller

```
    $obj = \App\EloquentModel\User::find(1);
    return $this->response->item($obj, new UserTransformer);
```

And in my UserTransformer

```
public function transform(User $trans)
{
    return [
        'id'            => (int) $trans->id,
        'name'          => $trans->name,
        'description'   => $trans->description
    ];
}
```

Applying those things removed the key "data" for single item.

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Juan",
   "description": "The BOss"
}
```

But when I try to make it an Array. User::all(), the response has the "data" key.

Thanks.

Comment: I also tried this>

$this->app->bind('Dingo\Api\Transformer\Adapter\Fractal', function($app) {
            $fractal = $app->make('\League\Fractal\Manager');
                $serializer = new \League\Fractal\Serializer\ArraySerializer;

            $fractal->setSerializer($serializer);
            return new \Dingo\Api\Transformer\Adapter\Fractal($fractal);
        });

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the CustomSerializer, a class that is extend by ArraySerializer. Thanks to this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35603117/3150510)